# Not able to create AppEngine connected Android project in eclipse?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I've installed google plugin for eclipse. On creating project using **New > project > AppEngine Connected Android Project**, the wizard gets stuck at `Generating cloud endpoints library`. On investigating, I found out that the following error is being thrown

```
RegisterActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

How to tackle this issue?

Comment: Sometimes this happens if you have an older version of the app-engine sdk.  AppEngine connected android project should work with app-engine sdk >= 1.7.5.  But you need to make sure to set your default app-engine sdk to that version or higher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "AppEngine Connected Android Project" is old.  On my installation of Eclipse 4.2 and the current GPE I don't see that option.  Endpoints has replaced that.

The easiest way for you to proceed, IMO, is to create an Android project, then use the "Generate AppEngine Backend" wizard (i.e. select the Android project in the package explorer, then find that wizard on the Google sub-menu).

That will create an App Engine project with endpoints, and configure it to automatically copy its endpoint libraries to your Android project when you select 'generate cloud endpoint libraries'.

Comment: I just tried it like you suggested. It created the AppEngine project on "Generate AppEngine Backend". However, stuck again in when generating clould endpoint libraries. I use Eclipse 4.2 and GPE 3.2.

Comment: Tom, the wizard gets stuck at "Generating cloud endpoints library" because it is downloading the endpoints source. The source is being downloaded even on rebuild. Are you facing such a thing? Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: That wizard uses a Google service to generate the source - there is no way to avoid that.  When the wizard completes check the error log to see if there were any issues.